# VBA Error Handle - Resume and print error

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I'm trying to build an structure like this below.
where I have a loop and sometimes one of the loop steps can return error but I want to skip it and continue loop till the end.

But if any of the loops execution had error I want to know it printing in a cell something like "Missing loads: ( 1 ,20 ,36)" Where this number are unique values that one of my variables on the loop receive.

So I think every time one of my loop executions return error I need to build a list of this variable value and at the end of the loop process use this list to return this error msg.

**UPDATE:**

For the below I want to know the list of any eventual "sProdId" value that was in the SQL query wen it fail to execute by ANY error. Usually it try to insert #Value in a numeric SQL field.

```
    Sub SavetoSQL()

        Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
        Dim iRowNo As Integer

        Dim Ddate
        Ddate = Range("refdate")

        Dim RngRefdate As Date
        RngRefdate = DateSerial(Year(Ddate), Month(Ddate), Day(Ddate))



 With Sheets("Hist Prods temp")

     'Open a connection to SQL Server
            conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=XXXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXXXX;User Id=XXXX;Password=XXXXXXX;"

            'Skip the header row
            iRowNo = 2

            'Loop until empty cell in sRefDate
            Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
                sRefDate = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
                sProdId = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
                sPrice = .Cells(iRowNo, 3)
                sValue = .Cells(iRowNo, 4)
                sDV01 = .Cells(iRowNo, 5)
                sDelta1 = .Cells(iRowNo, 6)
                sDeltaPct = .Cells(iRowNo, 7)
                sGamma = .Cells(iRowNo, 8)
                sVega = .Cells(iRowNo, 9)
                sTheta = .Cells(iRowNo, 10)
                sDelta2 = .Cells(iRowNo, 11)
                sIVol = .Cells(iRowNo, 12)

'Generate and execute sql statement to import the excel rows to SQL Server table

conn.Execute "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Prices] ([Date],[Id_Product],[Price],[Value],[DV01],[Delta1$],[Delta%],[Gamma$],[Vega$],[Theta$],[Delta2$],[Ivol],[Last_Update]) values ('" & sRefDate & "', '" & sProdId & "'," & sPrice & "," & sValue & "," & sDV01 & "," & sDelta1 & "," & sDeltaPct & "," & sGamma & "," & sVega & "," & sTheta & "," & sDelta2 & "," & sIVol & ",GETDATE())"


 iRowNo = iRowNo + 1

 Loop

 conn.Close
 Set conn = Nothing

 End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: Comparing my answer to Paul's, I am now slightly unsure whether (after error) you wished to perform remaining operations in the current loop iteration (Paul) or jump to next loop iteration (me). Mine can become the former by changing `GoTo CurrRecFail` to `Resume Next`.

Comment: Just to be 100% clear... If the loop for sProdId #25 throws an error at any point, you are done with #25 and moving on to the next record? Secondly, if on sProdId #25, #32, and #45 you have #VALUE errors in columns 8 and 10, do you want to see `"Missing loads: (25, 32, 45)` **or** `"Missing loads: (25, 25, 32, 32, 45, 45)` **or** `"Missing loads: 25 (8), 25 (10), 32 (8), 32 (10), 45 (8), 45 (10)`?

Comment: Yes, if I have any error that one row fail to insert into sql I will skip it and move to the next row of my sheet.   I don't need to see what the column caused the error just want to see for what sProdId  I had error, so just "Missing loads: (25, 32, 45)".

Comment: Then my answer should do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are a bit confused about Error Handling in VBA, have a look into Chip's website on proper [Error Handling in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm).

Your code should be something like,

```
Sub MyMacro()
On Error GoTo Errhandler
    Dim errLog As String
    Do Until
        ' My loop code
        'Save variable X value in a list of error values.
    Loop
ExitErrHandler:
    If Len(errLog) > 0 Then
        Range("M2") = "Missing loads: (" & Left(errLog, Len(errLog) - 2) & ")"
    End If 
    Exit Sub

Errhandler:
    'Make a Note of the Error Number and substitute it with 1234
    If Err.Number = 1234 Then
        ' If an error occurs, display a message in a cell with all X values on the list.
        errLog = errLog & yourUniqueValue & ", "
        Resume Next
    Else
        MsgBox "Another Error occurred." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
        Resume ExitErrHandler
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: My understanding was that the OP was logging which record IDs failed. If multiple lines in a single iteration of his loop throw an error, your code will print that index multiple times in the error string.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff - Agreed, but based on the pseudo code the OP has posted, this is one solution. Yours might be correct too, but without proper/actual code it is hard to judge.

Comment: Hi, My loop execute a single line command that loop in a specific sheet line by line where in each line I have many columns values that I pass as parameter for an a SQL insert string command. Some times expected parameter receives #value from excel and It drops an exception that stop my whole loop. I don't want it, I wish to continue execute my loop for the other rows. At the end on the sub execution I wish to see in a cell what rows I had error, the first variable that I use as argument in my loop is an unique Id, so for all of this guys I'll be using this value to append in my list.

Comment: If you could update your original post with the full code, with the error number and message, we might be able to help you better.

Comment: @Flib Yes I agree with Paul. Please clarify in your original post. I assume that code would throw an error when you assign the parameter  but I guess it could wait until query execution to throw. I don't have time to test right now but if you include the error info it would help a lot. Also, this assumes you are actually using Parameter objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes no sense because you are turning off error handling (`On Error GoTo 0`) before you ever get to the loop code that would throw the error.

Here is one way to do it. I have my error handler inside the loop. It appends the x value to a string. Because `x = x + 1` is in the error handler you don't have to worry about `x` not incrementing when you get an error. If you only care about certain `Err.Number` values, then change the `if` statement in my error handler. At the end of the code I print the error message to cell `A1` of `Sheet2` if and only if the error message string has at least one value. Otherwise I reset that output cell. `On Error GoTo -1` is important to reset the error handler.

```
Sub MyMacro()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim errMsg As String
    Dim outWs As Worksheet
    Set outWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    errMsg = ""

    On Error GoTo CurrRecFail
    x = 1
    Do Until x = 15
        ' My loop code

CurrRecFail:
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            errMsg = errMsg & x & ", "
        End If
        On Error GoTo -1
        x = x + 1

    Loop

    If Len(errMsg) > 0 Then
        outWs.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Missing Loads: " & Left(errMsg, Len(errMsg) - 2)
    Else
        outWs.Cells(1, 1).Value = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

The code above will jump to the next loop iteration when it hits an error. If you wish instead to proceed through the rest of the lines in the current loop iteration, change `On Error GoTo CurrRecFail` to `On Error Resume Next` and delete the line `CurrRecFail:` which is now a meaningless label.